# Java throw an exception if file has an invalid value/character

Tags: java, file, exception, throw

I have a txt, and I want to scan it and each time I read an integer I want to input it into an array I've already created.

How can I throw an exception whenever it reads something other than an int , for example String,double or even an empty line?

This is how I read the file, and complete the array:

```
    file= new Scanner(new File(file_name));

    int[] txt = new int[cnt]; // cnt , the number of lines in my txt

    while ( file.hasNextInt()) {
        txt[count] = file.nextInt(); 
        count++;
    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: read the javadocs - do not use `nextInt` and `hasNextInt` if you want process other stuff

Answer (score 4):

Change `hashNextInt()` to `hasNext()` and you'll get an exception as requested,

```
while (file.hasNextInt()) {
```

to

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Elliott's answer, if you want to detect the problem *without* throwing an exception:

```
   while (file.hasNext()) {
        if (file.hasNextInt()) {
            txt[count] = file.nextInt(); 
            count++;
        } else {
            System.error.println(file.next() + " is not an int"); // also skips bad data
        }
   }
```

(Hint: read and try to understand the logic ....)